# multinavibar not working in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using multinavbar but when i see in mobile toggle and menu are not working

here's the code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="height: 114px;margin-top: -51px;width: 1134px;margin-left: 143px;">     
    <div class="navbar-header" style="  margin-top: 29px;">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">News</a></div>

    </div>


</div>
<div class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-top: -19px;width: 1134px;margin-left: 143px;height: 45px;">       <div class="navbar-header">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">NEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">MOVIE NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHER NEWS</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">REVIEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">MOVIE REVIEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AUDIO REVIEWS</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">VIDEOS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">TRAILERS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">POPULAR VIDEOS </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Audio launch in US is a bad idea </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SHORTS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHERS </a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li><a href="#about">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">KIDS</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right" style="margin-top: -22px;">
        <div class="navbar-text"></div>
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


    <!-- Fixed navbar --><!-- 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">NEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">MOVIE NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHER NEWS</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">REVIEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">MOVIE REVIEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AUDIO REVIEWS</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">VIDEOS <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">TRAILERS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">POPULAR VIDEOS </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Audio launch in US is a bad idea </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SHORTS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHERS </a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
             <li><a href="#about">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">KIDS</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
  <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
              <input type="text" class="form-control">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             </button>
             </span>
             </div>



          </ul> -->

    </div>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

when i see in mobile it's not showing toggle and dropdown not working  any help would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: did you reference jQuery?

Comment: please see this exemple, http://www.bootply.com/1uftqpdgoQ .... that's true ;)

Comment: yes i see but in that toggle is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your navbar in a `div.container`.

Then, you need to address the correct data-target with your toggle-button. in your case, it would be `.navbar-collapse` instead of `#navbar` (which doesn't even exists in your example, as far as i digged into it - there is one in the code you commented out though ;) )

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">     
      <div class="navbar-header" style="  margin-top: 29px;">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">News</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      </div>
  
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">NEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">MOVIE NEWS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">OTHER NEWS</a></li>
  
                </ul>
              </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">REVIEWS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">MOVIE REVIEWS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">AUDIO REVIEWS</a></li>
  
                </ul>
              </li>
               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">VIDEOS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">TRAILERS </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">POPULAR VIDEOS </a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Audio launch in US is a bad idea </a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">SHORTS </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">OTHERS </a></li>
  
                </ul>
              </li>
               <li><a href="#about">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">KIDS</a></li>
  
          </ul>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right" style="margin-top: -22px;">
          <div class="navbar-text"></div>
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>
  
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

IMO, the "multi-navbar" is a bit useless. you could gladly merge then (put the header in the collapsable navbar instead of creating a seperate navbar just for the word...)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/qhuuLLr5/1/) **

This works fine..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NEWS</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               NEWS <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">MOVIE NEWS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Other NEWS</a></li>

           </ul>
         </li>

         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               REVIEWS <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">MOVIE REVIEWS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">AUDIO REVIEWS</a></li>

           </ul>
         </li>

         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               VIDEOS <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">TRAILERS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">POPULAR VIDEOS </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Audio launch in US is a bad idea </a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SHORTS </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OTHERS </a></li>

           </ul>
         </li>
           <li><a href="#about">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">KIDS</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

</nav>
```